# How to watch user requests from server?

Tags: javascript, http, servlets, jakarta-ee, web

I am developing a website using J2EE(JSP,struct2) and Apache Container. My website will be some kind of scial media webiste like facebook.
All the thing I like to do is to change the user login status in database to active after user login and change it again after user logouts. Those active user list has to be shown to other users as well.

All I am thinking is to change user active status as soon as user login to the website and will use ajax for up-to-date active user list. The thing I have trouble is that I want the server to check if the user is still active and still using the website every 5 seconds or whatever.
To do so, all I am thinking is to watch the user from server if it is still sending the requests to the server. How can I watch like that?? Where can I read the tutorials to write such cde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 2 parts to solve your requirements.

- JavaScript on client
- Ajax receiver on server

Client:

On the client side can you use a idle handler which sends a request after some idle time on the user side.

Choose one of this solution
https://www.startpage.com/do/asearch?cat=&query=inactivity+user+javascript

Server:

On the server side just receive the Ajax request and write it to a DB. Afterwards you can do whatever ever you need with this record

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:
First: Using something like socket.io instead of AJAX in order to make it more 
lightweight on the server side.
Second: Consider delegating the inactivity detection and announcement to the client.